# How to disconnect all connection on a session?

Tags: node.js, opentok

I wanna to disconnect all connection on a session from server but i just find how to dissconnect a connection by using forceDisconnect. Besides, I wanna destroy session when all connection disconnected and destroy token when a connection disconnected

Answer (score 0):

Opentok SDET here,

You can use *forceDisconnect*, if you want to trigger the disconnection from a single point, or use *disconnect* and capture *StreamDestroyed* events in remote peers, to act accordingly.
Regarding sessions, you don't need to destroy sessions, just don't reuse them, and create a new one.
Tokens expire, so you don't need to worry about them, either.

I hope this helps.