# Tokbox : How do you disconnect all clients from server side for a session?

Tags: node.js, opentok, tokbox

I'm trying to terminate all Tokbox connections from server-side. I have the logic the terminate connections from client-side, however, clients are unreliable that it may not get to disconnect properly(network issue, sudden app termination etc).

I'm aware of the `forceDisconnect` option with a `connectionId` either from the SDK or REST API. However, I can't find an option to list all open connections from a sessionId from server side.

I'm also aware that, I can just wait for sessions to expire. ([How to disconnect all connection on a session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56542323/how-to-disconnect-all-connection-on-a-session#))

However, waiting for the tokens to expire(or the session to terminate on Tokbox Server side), costs much more, especially if you are using auto-archiving option. If you don't explicitly terminate your sessions, you'll get billed for your session + up to 1 hour of archiving.

In summary, when a tokbox session is over, what I want to do is

- Clients will try to disconnect their own connections(Done)
- If clients, for some reason, fail to do #1, server will list all active connections.
- call `forceDisconnect` on each connections from #2

Answer (score 0):

OpenTok Developer Advocate here.

@pompiamp is on the right track here. The best way to do this is to use the [Stream Monitoring webhook](https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/session-monitoring/#monitoring-streams).

That webhook will send events to your server for `streamCreated` and `streamDestroyed` events. The payload will resemble:

```
{
    "sessionId": "2_MX4xMzExMjU3MX5-MTQ3MDI1NzY3OTkxOH45QXRr",
    "projectId": "123456",
    "event": "streamCreated",
    "timestamp": 1470258860571,
    "stream": {
        "id": "63245362-e00e-4834-8371-9397deb3e452",
        "connection": {
            "id": "c053fcc8-c681-41d5-8ec2-7a9e1434a21e",
            "createdAt": 1470257688143,
            "data": ""
        },
        "createdAt": 1470258845416,
        "name": "",
        "videoType": "camera"
    }
}
```

You'll notice the payload includes a `stream.connection.id` property.

Then add some capability in your application to know the session is over and call `forceDisconnect` for any streams you still show as not destroyed.

Comment: i am too looking for this solution. disconnect all clients i need connection object for forcedisconnect() method, but in listStream() method i am getting only streams details not connection object. please reply.

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question at all.

Comment: @Rahly, you're right. Not sure what happened there. Copy/paste of another answer perhaps. Updated answer with solution.

Comment: I think they want connectionCreated/connectionDestroyed as they want to force disconnect a user.  While the streamCreated/Destroyed does give you the connection id, i think it might be overkill for what is needed.

Comment: Could be. It depends on the goal. If you're looking to make sure everyone leaves the session, I'd suggest having your application handle navigating the user away rather than calling `forceDisconnect` for each of them. 

If your goal is focused on stopping any publishing for billing or archive reasons, you'd want to know connections related to streams and not all connections.

In both cases, the best solution is likely very short session tokens for users, navigating users away from sessions on meeting end, and not re-issuing tokens for a session after meeting end.

Answer (score 0):

We are having the same problem, forceDisconnect only accepts ConnectionId as parameter.
But with serverSDK the only thing you can get is StreamIds..

Our approach is by using Session Monitoring to get the connectionsIds

See https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/session-monitoring/

Maybe you can listen to that hook and store in your database the connectionIds received

Is not the best solution, but maybe an approach

Another solution could be to disconnect users client-side:

https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/moderation/js/